# In emacs, can I set up the *Messages* buffer so that it tails?

Tags: emacs

Basically I want the ******Messages****** buffer to always scroll to the bottom when a new message arrives.

Can I do that?

I found `auto-revert-tail-mode` but that works for buffers that are visiting files. 
When I tried it in the Messages buffer, it popped an error:
`auto-revert-tail-mode: This buffer is not visiting a file`

Comment: When the cursor is at the end of that buffer, it stays there even if new messages arrive.  I take it it's not enough to you?

Comment: Yes, in Emacs 23.2.1 at least, \*Messages\* tails by default, unless you manually move point from the EOF (and moving it back again resumes the tailing behaviour). `auto-revert-tail-mode` does not appear to do anything obviously different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For multiple frames you probably want:

```
(defadvice message (after message-tail activate)
  "goto point max after a message"
  (with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (walk-windows (lambda (window)
                    (if (string-equal (buffer-name (window-buffer window)) "*Messages*")
                        (set-window-point window (point-max))))
                  nil
                  t)))
```

Comment: Nice, but you should probably use `get-buffer-window-list` instead of walk-windows + a filter.

Answer (score 5):

Just put point at the end of the buffer <kbd>M-></kbd>. If you don't manually move it it will stay there -- IOW, you will always see the tail.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't true... it certainly doesn't work on any of the emacs I have around.

Comment: @nicferrier Yes, it does work.  See the other comments under the question for more detail about what is meant. Be sure you use `M->` and not just other cursor movements, to get point at `point-max`.

Comment: It's true that point stays at the end of the buffer. But point doesn't stay visible (27.0.50). I think staying visible is part of what is meant by "tail"-like behaviour in this question.

Comment: @ded7: Point is always visible - it is the buffer position of the cursor, which is never outside the visible portion of the buffer/window.

Comment: @Drew we're talking here about what happens when the active window is displaying a buffer other than the \*Messages\* buffer, but the \*Messages\* buffer is visible in another window. When that's the case, it is possible that the maximum buffer position of the \*Messages\* buffer is not visible, even though you may have left point in \*Messages\* at what was, at the time, the maximum buffer position.

Comment: I see. So you're talking about `window-point`. In that case, @Peter's answer or similar is relevant. I also submitted Emacs bug (enhancement request) #36343  just now, which suggests that users be given an option to have this done automatically. (Bug #36343 itself is really about `C-h e`, however.)

Answer (score 2):

This code seems a bit overkill, but a the simple `(goto-char (point-max))` wasn't working for me:

```
(defadvice message (after message-tail activate)
  "goto point max after a message"
  (with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (let ((windows (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)))
      (while windows
        (set-window-point (car windows) (point-max))
        (setq windows (cdr windows))))))
```

Comment: you are prolific, Mr Jackson.

Comment: The form above using walk-windows seems more elegant to me.

Comment: @Nordlöw: at minimum, the `(while windows ...)` here is better written as in the `walk-windows` version: `(mapc (lambda (w) (set-window-point w (point-max))) windows)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that uses the new advice style.

```
(defun message-buffer-goto-end-of-buffer (&rest args)
  (let* ((win (get-buffer-window "*Messages*"))
         (buf (and win (window-buffer win))))
    (and win (not (equal (current-buffer) buf))
         (set-window-point
          win (with-current-buffer buf (point-max))))))

(advice-add 'message :after 'message-buffer-goto-end-of-buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

i run 23.3 and there were still way too many occasions where the built-in 'solution' and the orginal defadvice on the message function just didn't cut it, so i wrapped that code in a list / toggle / timer set up and it's working beautifully - no more frustration when debugging!

it's generic, so works on any buffer, although i only really use it for..

```
(toggle-buffer-tail "*Messages*" "on")
```

..hope it's useful to someone.

```
;alist of 'buffer-name / timer' items
(defvar buffer-tail-alist nil)
(defun buffer-tail (name)
  "follow buffer tails"
  (cond ((or (equal (buffer-name (current-buffer)) name)
         (string-match "^ \\*Minibuf.*?\\*$" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))))
        ((get-buffer name)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer name)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (let ((windows (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)))
          (while windows (set-window-point (car windows) (point-max))
         (with-selected-window (car windows) (recenter -3)) (setq windows (cdr windows))))))))

(defun toggle-buffer-tail (name &optional force)
  "toggle tailing of buffer NAME. when called non-interactively, a FORCE arg of 'on' or 'off' can be used to to ensure a given state for buffer NAME"
  (interactive (list (cond ((if name name) (read-from-minibuffer 
      (concat "buffer name to tail" 
        (if buffer-tail-alist (concat " (" (caar buffer-tail-alist) ")") "") ": ")
    (if buffer-tail-alist (caar buffer-tail-alist)) nil nil
           (mapcar '(lambda (x) (car x)) buffer-tail-alist)
        (if buffer-tail-alist (caar buffer-tail-alist)))) nil)))
  (let ((toggle (cond (force force) ((assoc name buffer-tail-alist) "off") (t "on")) ))
    (if (not (or (equal toggle "on") (equal toggle "off"))) 
      (error "invalid 'force' arg. required 'on'/'off'") 
      (progn 
        (while (assoc name buffer-tail-alist) 
           (cancel-timer (cdr (assoc name buffer-tail-alist)))
           (setq buffer-tail-alist (remove* name buffer-tail-alist :key 'car :test 'equal)))
        (if (equal toggle "on")
            (add-to-list 'buffer-tail-alist (cons name (run-at-time t 1 'buffer-tail name))))
        (message "toggled 'tail buffer' for '%s' %s" name toggle)))))
```

edit: changed functionality to display tail at the bottom of the window

Comment: put it up on github here (just for my own convenience) http://github.com/mbriggs/buffer-tail.el

Answer (score 1):

Here's an amendment over **Peter**'s / **Trey**'s solutions

```el
(defun modi/messages-auto-tail (&rest _)
  "Make *Messages* buffer auto-scroll to the end after each message."
  (let* ((buf-name "*Messages*")
         ;; Create *Messages* buffer if it does not exist
         (buf (get-buffer-create buf-name)))
    ;; Activate this advice only if the point is _not_ in the *Messages* buffer
    ;; to begin with. This condition is required; otherwise you will not be
    ;; able to use `isearch' and other stuff within the *Messages* buffer as
    ;; the point will keep moving to the end of buffer :P
    (when (not (string= buf-name (buffer-name)))
      ;; Go to the end of buffer in all *Messages* buffer windows that are
      ;; *live* (`get-buffer-window-list' returns a list of only live windows).
      (dolist (win (get-buffer-window-list buf-name nil :all-frames))
        (with-selected-window win
          (goto-char (point-max))))
      ;; Go to the end of the *Messages* buffer even if it is not in one of
      ;; the live windows.
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (goto-char (point-max))))))
(advice-add 'message :after #'modi/messages-auto-tail)
```