# How to follow the end of *Messages* buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In emacs, can I set up the *Messages* buffer so that it tails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682033/in-emacs-can-i-set-up-the-messages-buffer-so-that-it-tails)

I am playing with Elisp, and I find convenient to have the ***Messages*** buffer always open in a window in my frame.

I discovered recently that sometimes the buffer stops following the last line in the file. If I want to see the last appended lines in this buffer, I need to go in the buffer and jump to the end manually, with <kbd>M-></kbd>. Which quite annoying and disruptive.

I am trying to reproduce the "tail -f" command line, in a buffer. Of course `'auto-revert-tail-mode` complains that the ***Messages*** is not a visited file... As a consequence, this mode does not want to work. But it gave me the idea to add a function hook when the buffer is modified. That function would jump to `(point-max)` each time that buffer is modified.

Here is my own attempt, invoked from ***Messages*** buffer, with <kbd>M-:</kbd>:
`(add-hook 'after-change-functions (lambda (s e l) (goto-char (point-max)) nil) nil t)`

But it does not work. The `(point)` remains in the same place while I see the buffer is growing... The lambda function does not produce any error, otherwise it would have been removed from the `'after-change-functions` hook and <kbd>C-h k</kbd> `'after-change-functions` shows it is present.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: The same question has been asked before I think, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682033/in-emacs-can-i-set-up-the-messages-buffer-so-that-it-tails

Comment: Thank you for noticing that @elemakil ! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess using the method in the linked question (the solution by Trey Jackson) should be faster as it wouldn't hook into the `post-command-hook` (which is probably executed numerous times without write operations to `*Message*`). Instead the code is executed when emacs' own method for tailing the `*Message*` buffer is called (from my understanding).

Comment: @elemakil The solution in the older question is less reliable because it overrides `message`. Emacs can display content in the echo area without going through `message`; for example, the output of `M-:` doesn't go through `message`, and neither do `princ` and `prin1`. `post-command-hook` is invoked once at the end of every user command, but the amount of work performed by yves Baumes's function (and mine) is minimal, it just updates the point. Adding a small amount of code to `post-command-hook` is a regular occurrence in Emacs programming.

Comment: Otherwise, just to let you know, the issue is happening because of a regression. I filled in a [bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12855) after some discussion with a dev on gnu.emacs.help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the point position from `after-change-functions` is very dangerous anyway because it can break some types of edit to the buffer (for example, Emacs compresses multiple consecutive messages with the same content). However, for your purposes the `post-command-hook` is more than sufficient and much safer, so you can just use this:

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((messages (get-buffer "*Messages*")))
              (unless (eq (current-buffer) messages)
                (with-current-buffer messages
                  (goto-char (point-max)))))))
```

The hook will make sure the point in `*Messages*` is at the end of buffer after every command, unless you're currently editing the `*Messages` buffer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've made my own one with `set-window-point`.

```
(defun tail-f-msgs ()
  "Go to the end of Messages buffer."
  (let ((msg-window (get-buffer-window "*Messages*")))
    (if msg-window
        (with-current-buffer (window-buffer msg-window)
          (set-window-point msg-window (point-max))))))

;; Make the Messages buffer stick to the end.
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'tail-f-msgs)
```